# Javascript function not showing alert properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have written the following code in my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas Test</title>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body onload="initialise();loadCanvas();">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600">   
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And this in my `main.js` file:

```
var clickCount;
var gameCanvas;
var myImage;

function initialise()
{
    clickCount = 0;
    gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    myImage = new image();
    myImage.src = "../img/test.png";
}

function loadCanvas()
{
    alert(clickCount);
}
```

The code is supposed to show a alert saying `0` on the page load, but the alert shows `undefined` instead. So I updated the code like this in `index.html`

```
<body onload="initialise();">
```

And modified the function `initialise()` like this in `main.js`:

```
function initialise()
{
    clickCount = 0;
    gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    myImage = new image();
    myImage.src = "../img/test.png";
    loadCanvas();
}
```

Now the alert doesn't come at all. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? I am really new to HTML5 and javascript, and am really stuck up with this. Couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a capitalization error:

```
myImage = new image();
```

should be:

```
myImage = new Image(); // notice the capital I
```

If you check your console for errors, you'll see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined
```

which points to where the problem is. This error was breaking your script and the alert line was never reached.

Comment: Did this, still no luck. It is still not showing any alert.

Comment: Impossible, I copied the code here and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7wGYG/ There has to be something else then.

Comment: Great, what was the problem?

Comment: Seems like it was some error with my apache server. The code was saved but the browser was still loading the old code. Got it rectified now after restarting the server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn to check the browser error console to see where your script errors are.

You need to change this:

```
new image();
```

to this:

```
new Image();
```

That causes a script error which aborts the initialise function.

Comment: Did this, still no luck. It is still not showing any alert.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT - then you must have some other script error.  Check the browser error console and see what other errors are showing.

Comment: I am using firebug. Can you tell me where to check for that? I am pretty new. I have got no idea debugging javascript.

Comment: Ok.. Seems like it was some error with my apache server. The code was saved but the browser was still loading the old code. Got it rectified now after restarting the server.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT - A google search for "browser error console" will give you lots of useful answers.  The particular instructions vary by browser.

Answer (score 2):

Practice using some debugger like firebug or chrome debugging tools . It can be very helpful to find errors like this .